# Authenticated with SSSD (LDAP) but use /etc/passwd after login

Tags: pam, sssd

I have the following setting:

- I have users in two different domains from two different organizations (separated AD installations) with users `user@DOMAIN` and `user@OTHERDOMAIN`
- On the system, these users map to `user_d` and `user_o`.
- For performance (and other reasons), user login to UID mapping, GIDs, and Gecos information are managed in `/etc/{passwd,group}`.
- The AD servers are unaware of the mapping of logins to UID and the GIDs.

I am currently using CentOS 7.4 and consequently sssd 1.15.2 to realize this.

I have it *almost* working  (see below for an excerpt of the relevant configuration parts). I can login with `user@DOMAIN` and locally I am (result of `whoami`) `user_d`. However, my uid is set to `10008`. Some group assignment is bogus but my groups from `/etc/groups` is correct.

The output of `getent passwd user_d` also gives me the correct result from the `/etc/passwd` file.

It looks like I'm only missing a little piece of the puzzle...

#### sssd configuration

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = DOMAIN,OTHER

[domain/DOMAIN]
access_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
id_provider = ldap
use_fully_qualified_names = True
full_name_format = %1$s_d

ldap_access_filter = objectClass=person
ldap_tls_reqcert = allow
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_user_object_class = person
ldap_user_name = sAMAccountName
ldap_user_fullname = displayName
ldap_id_mapping = False
ldap_uri = <ldap URI>
ldap_search_base = <search base>
ldap_default_bind_dn = <bind user>
ldap_default_authtok = <bind user password>
```

#### /etc/pam.d/password-auth-local

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     sufficient    pam_sss.so
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

#### /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     file

s sss
shadow:     files
group:      files
#initgroups: files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns myhostname

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files     

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files

netgroup:   nisplus

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files nisplus
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to resolve this appears to be the `sss_seed` and `sss_override_user` commands.

First, import all users that you want into the SSS cache using `sss_seed` (e.g., from the existing `/etc/passwd` file).

Then, override the attributes appropriately using `sss_override_user`.

Note that the documentation appears to be misleading, you will need one more colon `:` in the override import file than in `/etc/passwd` file (just appending one worked fine for me).